# Spreadsheets IF Greater than 0, make another cell equal this

Tags: arrays, if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I'm new to spreadsheets and I'm trying to do something like this:

If cell  H86 > 0, then make cell J93 have the same value as H86. However, if H86 < 0, then make the cell H93 equal H96.

I tried doing it like this:

```
=IFS(H86 > 0, J93 = H86, H86 < 0, H93 = H86)
```

I keep getting the output "False" in the cell I'm trying to do this in, instead of it changing the values in the other cells.
If what I'm doing isn't possible is there something I can do to achieve this?

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: Here's a copyhttps://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1uKGdZQu20gEseuEoSR8ohixck9ltw8-63Dki7H-ysLQ/edit?usp=sharing It's a bit unorganized (sorry about that) but the section I'm working on is towards the bottom of column "J" It's labeled "Ordering Activity Value." What I want to do is organize all the values in that section, where I have all the values that greater than 0, to be put in the "Actual Value for the project." The solution you put helped!! But how would I make it so that it works for the different columns because right now it can only sort out the values that are in column "H".

Comment: I know that the values greater than 0 are already only in the one column so this solution would work if I drag down the solution. But, in the future, some values might be in column "H" while other values might be in column "J." If you don't mind telling me, how does the solution work, I'm very interested in this!

Comment: I figured out that "" makes the value move over one column depending on how many "" there are, but is there a way to move the value down and up and to the left also?

Comment: to put values next to each other you do `={"a","b"}` to put them under each other you use semicolon `={"a";"b"}` respectively: `={"a","b";"c","d"}` etc. also instead of "" you can just use an empty cell or range. if you want AF I updated the answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on your wish paste this in H93:

```
=IF(H86 > 0, {"", "", H86}, 
 IF(H86 < 0, H96, ))
```

for arrayformula use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
 IF(H86:H90 > 0, {X86:X90, X86:X90, H86:H90}, 
 IF(H86:H90 < 0, {H96:H100*1, X86:X90, X86:X90}, )))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: I saw that it put the -3 in the "0 Value Cell" rather than the "Actual Value for Project" cell. Is there a way to remove the zeros that show up as well? https://imgur.com/a/YrKvxd2 Sometimes I'm going to get values like these, so is there a way to just not display the zeroes in these events and just display the numbers greater than 0?

Comment: try: `=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(""&
 IF(H86:H90 > 0, {X86:X90, X86:X90, H86:H90}, 
 IF(H86:H90 < 0, {H96:H100*1, X86:X90, X86:X90}, )), "^0$", ))`